# html preloader

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader

Are there any ways to do html preloader with jquery? Sorry, I can't find it. I mean show a small size image (loading image) when html is loading.

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do that; it's annoying.

And you may have problems (waiting for the timeout) in situations with broken (image) links.